# jQuery ajax request in loop on success does not displays data in HTML element

Tags: jquery, closures

When i running Ajax request in loop, ajax on success does not displays returned data...
Here is code:

```
url = ["../siteAdmin/statistics/queriesAjax.php", "../siteAdmin/statistics/geographyAjax.php"];
tabContainerId = ['tabs-2', 'tabs-3'];

for(var i=0, len=url.length; i < len; i++){
    console.log(tabContainerId[i]);
    jQuery("#"+tabContainerId[i]).html('<img src="../assets/images/loading.gif"/>');
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:url[i],
        data:{ from:from, to:to },
        success: function (msg) {
            jQuery("#"+tabContainerId[i]).html(msg);
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            showError("Error occurred.", tabContainerId[i]);
        }
    });
}
```

In HTML element i just see loading.gif.
Console.log(msg) on ajax success in browser console are displayed. But in HTML element- not.
If i set var i = 0 or var i = 1 data is displayed. 
Where i made a mistake?

Comment: This is a scoping issue.. You need to use closures in such cases

Comment: Could you explain it in more details please?

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous right.. So by the time the for loop is iterated , mostly the success function is not called yet.. So the current value of i will be 1 (Length of url array)..  As the i points to the same memory location... When you hit the success function both will be pointing to the same location .. So it will always be 1

Comment: But if i = 1 why in html element i see loading.gif . I think there should be other data. Or am I wrong?

Comment: That might be the loading gif for tabcontainer0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the variable `i` within your success callback, but by the time your callbacks are executed, `i` has almost certainly changed.

You have to force i to be part of the callback function's closure. One way to do this is to put the contents of the for loop into an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE):

```
url = ["../siteAdmin/statistics/queriesAjax.php", "../siteAdmin/statistics/geographyAjax.php"];
tabContainerId = ['tabs-2', 'tabs-3'];

for(var i=0, len=url.length; i < len; i++) {
    (function(idx) {
        console.log(tabContainerId[idx]);
        jQuery("#"+tabContainerId[idx]).html('<img src="../assets/images/loading.gif"/>');
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:url[idx],
            data:{ from:from, to:to },
            success: function (msg) {
                jQuery("#"+tabContainerId[idx]).html(msg);
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                showError("Error occurred.", tabContainerId[idx]);
            }
        });
    })(i);
}
```

In effect, this "saves" the value of `i` so it is the same when your callback functions use it.

I haven't run this code through lint or an interpreter, so there may be syntax errors.

Comment: Or you can set your AJAX call synchronized using param synch : true

Comment: @Bouillou .. but setting it to true is a bad idea

Comment: Why? Is it a bad practice? It is an $.ajax option

Comment: From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/): _Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active._